# ElasticSearch Java API AggregationBuilder filter/global "name" param causes malformed JSON

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I was trying to build a simple aggregation query using elasticsearch java API(version 5.5.0), but the "name" param taken by the filter / global methods of the AggregationBuilder causes a malformed JSON.

For example, I tried the first example [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/_bucket_aggregations.html)... 
Here's the relevant code section:

```
AggregationBuilder builder = 
  AggregationBuilders
  .global("agg")
  .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("genders").field("gender"));

Search search = new Search.Builder(builder.toString())
            .addIndex(INDEX_NAME)
            .addType(TYPE_NAME)
            .setParameter(Parameters.SIZE,0).build();

    JestClient jestClient = getJestClient();

    try {
        SearchResult result = jestClient.execute(search);
        System.out.println(result.getJsonString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This produces the following error message:

```
{
"error": {
"root_cause": [
  {
    "type": "parse_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to derive xcontent"
  }
],
"type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
"reason": "all shards failed",
"phase": "query",
"grouped": true,
"failed_shards": [
  {
    "shard": 0,
    "index": "index_name",
    "node": "UEjNVXkIQRSBCOpyqcq2dw",
    "reason": {
      "type": "parse_exception",
      "reason": "Failed to derive xcontent"
    }
  }
]
},
"status": 400
}
```

While debugging and watching the builder's value, I see it builds the follwing malformed JSON (Please mind the first element("agg") which comes from the "name" param of the "global" method):

```
"agg"{
  "global" : { },
  "aggregations" : {
    "genders" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "gender",
        "size" : 10,
        "min_doc_count" : 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count" : 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error" : false,
        "order" : [
          {
            "_count" : "desc"
          },
          {
            "_term" : "asc"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the simplest example, according to the documentation, ([here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/_bucket_aggregations.html) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-aggs.html)), modifying your code slightly like the below:

```
AggregationBuilder builder = AggregationBuilders.global("agg").subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("genders").field("gender"));
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(INDEX_NAME).setTypes(TYPE_NAME).setSize(0).addAggregation(builder).get();
//Global aggResult = response.getAggregations().get("agg"); //Global result can be used to retrieve values from the aggregation directly
System.out.println(response);
```

The code above (after initialization of the client) works correctly so there is definitely no issue with the AggregationBuilder from the java API.

Actually I don't understand why you wouldn't use the `SearchResponse` class as it is omnipresent through all the examples in the documentation.

Edit: Given that [link](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-java-clients-for-elasticsearch#jest), I believe your issue comes from how you create your search query, because you only use the aggregation, giving the output you show in your post, whereas the full query (**which seems needed by the Jest client**) should be like:

```
{
  "size" : 0,
  "aggregations" : {
    "agg" : {
      "global" : { },
      "aggregations" : {
        "genders" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "gender",
            "size" : 10,
            "min_doc_count" : 1,
            "shard_min_doc_count" : 0,
            "show_term_doc_count_error" : false,
            "order" : [
              {
                "_count" : "desc"
              },
              {
                "_term" : "asc"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Another edit**: Actually one workaround is to use the transport client to build the query, then inject it into the search through the JEST API, like below:

```
AggregationBuilder builder = AggregationBuilders.global("agg")
                .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("genders")
                        .field("gender"));
SearchRequestBuilder queryBuilder= client2.prepareSearch(INDEX_NAME)
        .setTypes(TYPE_NAME).setSize(0).addAggregation(builder); //client2 is a client initialized with the transport client
Search search = new Search.Builder(queryBuilder.toString()).addIndex("_all").addType("*").build();
SearchResult res = client.execute(search);
//          System.out.println(res.toString());
System.out.println(res.getJsonString());
```

P.S: I am also using the 5.5.0 version of the Elasticsearch client API.

Comment: You are correct, when I try using the TransportClient and build the search query with it, it works fine... the problem is, that due to historical reasons, we have our implementation of Jest connector, so I have to use that one in order to avoid large refactoring.

Comment: @esaar If you can use the TransportClient, you can use a workaround (albeit ugly) to build the query with it, then use the query with the JEST connector (see my last edit)